# Getting 404 Not Found while doing Integration testing in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a annoying error while doing Integration testing in asp.net core.

**Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).**

Below is my code.

**RegistrationControllerTests.cs**

```
public class RegistrationControllerTests : IClassFixture<TestFixture<TestStartup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public RegistrationControllerTests(TestFixture<TestStartup> fixture)
        {
            _client = fixture.Client;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void InitialiseTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            var testSession = TestStartup.GetDefaultRegistrationModel();

            //Act
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("/");
            //Assert
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Assert.True(responseString.Contains(testSession.FormId));
        }
    }
```

**TestStartup.cs**

```
public class TestStartup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IRegistrationRepository, ServiceUtilities>();
            services.AddTransient<IClientServiceConnector, ClientServiceValidation>();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        }

        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseFileServer();
            ConfigureRestAuthenticationSetting(enviroment);
            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }

        private void ConfigureRestAuthenticationSetting(IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(enviroment.ContentRootPath,"wwwroot"))
                .AddJsonFile("TestConfig.json");
            Configuration = config.Build();
        }

        private void ConfigureRoutes(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
        {
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Registration}/{action=Index}/{formId}");
        }

        public static RegistrationModel GetDefaultRegistrationModel()
        {
            return new RegistrationModel
            {
                FormId = "12345"
            };
        }
    }
```

**TestFixture.cs**

```
public class TestFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable
    {
        private const string SolutionName = "RegistrationApplication.sln";
        private readonly TestServer _server;
        public HttpClient Client { get; }

        public TestFixture()
            :this(Path.Combine("src"))
        {

        }
        protected TestFixture(string solutionRelativeTargetProjectParentDir)
        {
            var startupAssembly = typeof(TStartup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var contentRoot = GetProjectPath(solutionRelativeTargetProjectParentDir, startupAssembly);

            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
                .ConfigureServices(InitializeServices)
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .UseStartup(typeof(TStartup));


            _server = new TestServer(builder);

            Client = _server.CreateClient();
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44316/Registration");
        }

        protected virtual void InitializeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var startupAssembly = typeof(TStartup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var manager = new ApplicationPartManager();
            manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(startupAssembly));

            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ControllerFeatureProvider());
            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ViewComponentFeatureProvider());
            services.AddSingleton(manager);

        }
        private static string GetProjectPath(string solutionRelativePath, Assembly startupAssembly)
        {
            var projectName = "RegistrationApplication";
            var applicationBasePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
            do
            {
                var solutionFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, SolutionName));
                if (solutionFileInfo.Exists)
                {
                    return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, solutionRelativePath, projectName));
                }
                directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
            }
            while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);
            throw new NotImplementedException($"Solution root could not be located using application root {applicationBasePath}.");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Client.Dispose();
            _server.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to to commit TestConfig.json in GIT. That is why it was throwing 404 error as it could not find it. After committing the TestConfig.json file everything works like a charm.

Below is the code where TestConfig.json is being used.

```
 private void ConfigureRestAuthenticationSetting(IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(enviroment.ContentRootPath,"wwwroot"))
                .AddJsonFile("TestConfig.json");
            Configuration = config.Build();
        }
```